# remove Keys and values in python json

Tags: python

I have some data which looks like this :

```
{
  "key_value": [
    {
      "key": "name",
      "value": "kapil"
    },
    {
      "key": "age",
      "value": "36"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to convert it to look like this:

```
{
  "age": "36",
  "name": "kapil"
}
```

Would somebody be able to help with this?

I have already tried using `json.dumps()`

Comment: `json.dumps` only converts an object to JSON. You still need to create the object with the structure you need first

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? How did you use `json.dumps` exactly?

Comment: Hello @Michael M , yes it did solved the problem (apologies for late reply). I have no words to thank you and everyone who responded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you were trying to use `json.dumps`, but all you need to do is loop through all the pairs and add them to a new dictionary. Like this:

```
data = {
  "key_value": [
    {
      "key": "name",
      "value": "kapil"
    },
    {
      "key": "age",
      "value": "36"
    }
  ]
}

res = {}
for pair in data["key_value"]:
    res[pair["key"]] = pair["value"]
print(res)
```

Note that if your data is in JSON, then you need to use `json.loads()` to convert your JSON to a dictionary, then use `json.dumps()` to convert that dictionary back to a string that can be written to a file.